# How to exclude $ from process builder String parameter, to execute a shell command

Tags: groovy, command, echo, pid

I am trying to escape the "$" symbol when executing a echo $! command in java.

```
static def execSync(String command) throws Exception {
    log.info("exec(" + command + ")")
    String[] splited = command.split("\\s+")
    def listCommand = Arrays.asList(splited)
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder()
    processBuilder.command(listCommand)
    return processBuilder.start()
}

execSync("echo \$!") // returns $! when i'd like a pid
```

I have identified the problem to be in the command that is executed (ie: the code above) and not from my way of getting the stdout of the command (outputstream blabla). If your are absolutely sure it's not, i'll show more.

When i execute on my system (centOs 7) *"echo $!"* i obviously get a pid, for instance : 2626.

**I would mostly like to know if there is a way to do a "echo $!" like on the system with a string in my function ?** (regex or other stuff)

Otherwise,
ProcessBuilder.start returns a Process but doesn't seem to have a method to get the pid, only exitReturn, out/in/error stream... Since I execute the previous command with the method shown above, i though i could get the pid with a linux command.

So, is there a way to get the pid of the previous process ? (not realy what i seek but i can manage if there is no other way)

I'm stuck with java 8, when java 9 has a method "getPid"

Comment: `static def execSync` that ain't Java...

Comment: Ho boy yes it's groovy my bad thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you `.execute()` or use the `ProcessBuilder` directly, you can not directly use shell features.  It just allows to spawn processes with arguments.  You have to start a shell and make it execute your shell "script" (command).  E.g.

```
def listCommand = ["/bin/sh", "-c", command]
```